# Java JDOM XML: How move node one level up

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I have the following problem. I want to move a nodes and all their children one level up, example:

Original XML file:

```
<a>
  <r>
    <b>test</b>
    <c>
      <d>test</d>
      <e>test</e>
      <f>
        <k>ddd</k>
      </f>
    </c>
  </r>
</a>
```

So I want to get the tag `<r>` and all its sub-elements and move them one level up:

```
<r>
  <b>test</b>
  <c>
    <d>test</d>
    <e>test</e>
    <f>
      <k>ddd</k>
    </f>
  </c>
</r>
```

I did not find any function for that in JDOM2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root element is a bit special, try something like this:

```
document.setRootElement(document.getRootElement().getChild("r").detach());
```

The `detach` is necessary to detach the `r` element from its current parent (the `a`) so it can then be re-parented to be a direct child of the `Document` node.